# c# - Sql Table return value of last Register

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, parameters

All right. I need enter in a condition if have a PEIXE and ID_FICHA registered.

It returns the respective value for me on a global variable  `valor.retorna_IdFIcha` and `valor.retorna_nome_peixe`. More its returning the respective `ID_FICHA` and returning the last `PEIXE` registred.

Example:

```
PEIXE1          ID_FICHA1
PEIXE 2         ID_FICHA2
PEIXE 3         ID_FICHA3
```

It returns the respective parameter `ID_FICHA` and return `PEIXE 3`.

Code:

```
public void SEARCH_PEIXEFICHA(int param_ID, string param_peixe)
{
    SqlDataReader objReader;
    SqlCommand objcmd = null;

    vsql = "SELECT [ID_FICHA], [RGP], [PEIXE], [PESO], [QUANTIDADE], [DATA_REGISTRO] FROM cadastro WHERE ID_FICHA = @ID_FICHA and PEIXE = @PEIXE";

    if (this.Conectar())
    {
        try
        {
            objcmd = new SqlCommand(vsql, objCon);

            objcmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ID_FICHA", param_ID));
            objcmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PEIXE", param_peixe));

            objReader = objcmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (objReader.Read())
            {
                valor.retorna_IdFIcha = objReader.GetInt32(0);
                valor.retorna_nome_peixe = objReader.GetString(2);
            }
        }
        catch
        {
        }
        finally
        {
            this.Desconectar();
        }
    }
}

private void button_Concluir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        int t = 0;
        int i = Convert.ToInt32(txtb_idFicha.Text);
        int z = 0;

        List<string> _verifica_peixe = new List<string>();

        string DateTimesql = myDateTime.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");

        objSQL.Insert_Cadastro(i, 12, "Palmito", 12, 12, DateTimesql);

        for (int x = 0; x < comboBox1.Items.Count; x++)
        {
            _verifica_peixe.Add(comboBox1.GetItemText(comboBox1.Items[x]));
        }

        for(int x = 0; x < _verifica_peixe.Count; x++)
        {
            objSQL.SEARCH_PEIXEFICHA(i, _verifica_peixe[x]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you already know the two values passed as parameters then it is pointless to ask the same values to be returned back from the query

Comment: I know both passed as parameters, but I want it to make sure there is the two parameters.